# How to split logic and states from main component to multiple files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

yesterday I've asked how is it possible to "clean" my App.js file and separate logical ,mathematic or effect functions in different files ,so my main file will be nice and easy to read. I've got few answers to use *Custom Hooks* and they gave me an example of how to do it ,but I really don't get it. My Calculator App is after several code changes compared to code which I provided ,when I asked for first time.

I've tried to understand how it works ,or read [React official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) but nothing helped me.

The first thing that doesn't make sense to me is this. I've tried some basic customHook.  So far, for trying to make this work I've created file *OrangeButtonHook.js* which contains

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function useOrangeButtonHook(operator){
const [whichOrange,setWhichOrange] = useState({
    whichOrange : 'there should be some text'
})

return whichOrange;
}
```

and in my *App.js* file I'm simply importing it and using as they showed me in answer to my previous question

```
import useOrangeButtonHook from './Components/OrangeButtonHook';

const {whichOrange, setWhichOrange} = useOrangeButtonHook();
console.log(whichOrange) //this works ,and in my console is 'there should be some text'
```

But for better understanding I've tried to rename it to something that makes more sense to me.

```
//OrangeButtonHook.js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function useOrangeButtonHook(operator){
const [whichOrange,setWhichOrange] = useState({
    button : 'there should be some text'
})

return whichOrange;
}
```

But when I try to call it in *App.js* ,my console shows 'undefined'.

```
 const {whichOrange, setWhichOrange} = useOrangeButtonHook();
 console.log(whichOrange) //throws undefined
```

So I've tried to call it like this

```
 const {whichOrange, setWhichOrange} = useOrangeButtonHook();
 console.log(whichOrange.button) //this works throws lot of errors
```

I don't understand what is the problem ,and I don't understand how I'm supposed to separate these functions to different files. Problem is, for example this function is supposed to add class with effect on button ,when operator button is clicked.

```
function turnOnOrange(operator){
  setNumber(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    whichOrange:operator
  }))
  operator.className = 'orangeActivated';
}

function turnOffOrange(){
 number.whichOrange.className = 'orangeDisabled';
 setNumber(prevState => ({
   ...prevState,
   whichOrange:null
  }))
}
```

But these functions are called inside *getOperator()* function ,which is called when user click operator button.

```
 function getOperator(e){
   let operator = e.target;
     setNumber(prevState => ({
       ...prevState,
       operator:operator.name
     }))

    if(!number.whichOrange){
      turnOnOrange(e.target);
    }

    if(number.whichOrange){
      number.whichOrange.className='orangeDisabled';
      turnOnOrange(e.target)
    }
 }
```

Almost all of the operations and operations are "linked" to each other. Link for codesandbox ,so you can see whole Calculator App code and understand more what I'm talking about is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-sound-e7e3o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

I'll very appreciate if someone explains to me or show me how it works or how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when using your custom hook you'll receive what you've returned from it. You are returning `whichOrange` which is an object `{ button: "there should be some text" }`. You're trying to extract `{ whichOrange, setWhichOrange }` from it which is not present in object metioned above.

Secondly there is no point in making custom hook which is equivalent to using React.useState. Also custom hooks are rather used for extracting common logic to use in several places.

If you want to make code cleaner you should start with chunking logic that you have in App.js into smaller pieces. Then you should try to extract common logic so that you have as little code duplication as possible. Next you can try to simplify your logic so there is less if statements in your code.

For example take a look at this part of code:

```js
if (number.operator === "+") {
  result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
  setNumber((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    firstNumber: result,
    secondNumber: "",
    result: result,
    operator: "",
    displayed: prettyNumbers(result),
    numToReset: true,
  }));
  resizeFinalNumber(prettyNumbers(result));
  //MINUS
} else if (number.operator === "-") {
  result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
  setNumber((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    firstNumber: result,
    secondNumber: "",
    result: result,
    operator: "",
    displayed: prettyNumbers(result),
    numToReset: true,
  }));
  resizeFinalNumber(prettyNumbers(result));
  //MULTIPLY
} else if (number.operator === "x") {
  result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
  setNumber((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    firstNumber: result,
    secondNumber: "",
    result: result,
    operator: "",
    displayed: prettyNumbers(result),
    numToReset: true,
  }));
  resizeFinalNumber(prettyNumbers(result));
}
```

You can easly make it shorter and simplier to read by not diplicating setNumber so much:

```js
if (number.operator === "+") {
  result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
} else if (number.operator === "-") {
  result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
} else if (number.operator === "x") {
  result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
}

setNumber((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  firstNumber: result,
  secondNumber: "",
  result: result,
  operator: "",
  displayed: prettyNumbers(result),
  numToReset: true,
}));

resizeFinalNumber(prettyNumbers(result));
```

There is no point in calling exact same function in every single if statement. So I'd advise to start with that stuff(eliminating code duplication, extracting function that have nothing to do with React into separate files) and only later try to use custom hooks just to get used to them or separate common logic that can't be just a simple function.

Futher example:

```js
// You can use this function in multiple places
const getOperationResult = (firstNumber, secondNumber, operator) => {
  let result;
  
  if (number.operator === "+") {
    result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
  } else if (number.operator === "-") {
    result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
  } else if (number.operator === "x") {
    result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
  }

  return result
}

const result = getOperationResult(firstNumber, secondNumber, operation);

setNumber((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  firstNumber: result,
  secondNumber: "",
  result: result,
  operator: "",
  displayed: prettyNumbers(result),
  numToReset: true,
}));

resizeFinalNumber(prettyNumbers(result));
```

For starters I challenge you to get rid of at least 100 lines of code and make every file be at most 100 lines long ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) i’m not sure If I’m at that level so I can make it under 100 lines. Thats the reason why i asked About how to ‘clean’ that App.js file . But i’ll take a look at it and try to get rid of reapeatable code @Naszos